# Java do loop - string cannot be resolved

Tags: java, compiler-errors, do-while

Working on a simple dice rolling game using programmer defined methods in Java. Since I know the program needs to run at least once and then ask if the player wants to go again, I elected to use a do/while loop. I've never had to use one before, but I believe I set it up right.

My code is as follows, excluding the body of my main method contained within the loop, as well as the programmer defined methods.

```
do {
    // main METHOD BODY ..

    String proceed = ui.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Would you like to play again (yes/no)? ");

} while (proceed.charAt(0) == 'Y' || proceed.charAt(0) == 'y');
```

What I get from the Eclipse IDE at this point is "proceed cannot be resolved."

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Answer (score 6):

You need to declare it outside the `do`.

```
String proceed = null;
do {
  ...    
  proceed = ui.nextLine(); 
  ...    
} while (proceed.charAt(0) == 'Y' || proceed.charAt(0) == 'y');
```

When you declare it inside the `do`, its scope is only within that statement's body, and can't be resolved on the `while` part.

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it. Dopey  mistake on my part. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6):

proceed isn't in scope at the time it is being dereferenced in the while loop. Move the declaration of the proceed variable outside of the do.

```
String proceed;
do{

 main METHOD BODY

    proceed = ui.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Would you like to play again (yes/no)? ");

} while (proceed.charAt(0) == 'Y' || proceed.charAt(0) == 'y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting this to null initially and then giving it a value later, it's better to just define it's value to 'N' so another coder who comes along doesn't imply behavior associated to null and act accordingly.  This value should be 1 of 2 things... Y or N, don't initialize it to something other than it's two intended values.

You can also modify that while condition to be a bit cleaner by using a method there.  It's more descriptive of what you want to do and you can unit test the condition.

With modifications that amounts to:

```
String proceed="N";
while (this.playAgain(proceed)) { //playAgain performs the same test as you have in your while
     //your code
}
```

Second, on your code that is intentionally snipped, Make sure that consists of something like:

```
Game game = new Game();
game.play();
```

If you have a lot more code than that, it's too much in one spot.

Comment: in the example you game the loop would never execute since it is being initialized to "N" instead of "Y"